# InvalidOperationException: The view 'ListCart' was not found. The following locations were searched:

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Asp .net does not see View 'ListCart' even though I have one.

[The error it gives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03FT2.png)

[Folder View/Products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoUgg.png)

**Code of my View ListCart.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ListCart";
}
<style>
    td, th {
        padding: 10px;
    }
</style>
<script src="~/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".updateCart").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var quantity = $(".quantity_" + $(this).attr("data-id")).val();
            console.log(quantity);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:"@Url.Action("updateCart","Product")",
                data: {
                    id: $(this).attr("data-id"),
                    quantity:quantity
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("ListCart","Product")';
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="list-cart">
    <table class="cart" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>STT</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Total Price</th>
            <th>Update</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
        @{
            int STT = 0;
            foreach (var item in ViewBag.carts)
            {
                string txt_class = "quantity_" + item.Product.idProduct;
                STT++;
                int total = item.Product.Price * item.Quantity;
                <tr>
                    <td>@STT</td>
                    <td>@item.Product.Title</td>
                    <td><img src="~/images/@item.Product.UrlImage" width="100" height="100" /></td>
                    <td><input type="number" class="@txt_class" value="@item.Quantity" /></td>
                    <td>@item.Product.Price</td>
                    <td>@total</td>
                    <td><a href="" data-id="@item.Product.idProduct" class="updateCart">Update</a></td>
                    <td><a asp-controller="Products" asp-action="deleteCart" asp-route-id="@item.Product.idProduct">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

**My method code in Products controller Products.ListCart**

```
  public IActionResult ListCart()
        {
            var cart = HttpContext.Session.GetString("cart");//get key cart
            if (cart != null)
            {
                List<CartItem> dataCart = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CartItem>>(cart);
                if (dataCart.Count > 0)
                {
                    ViewBag.carts = dataCart;
                    return View();
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

Other Views work, only View ListCart.cshtml does not work.
If you right-click on the ListCart method, and select go to view, it redirects me correctly.

Comment: Hi @Try Parse, does your Products folder locate in Views folder? It is better for you to share the whole project structure and share your Startup.cs or Program.cs.

Comment: The problem was solved by deleting and creating a new ListCart.cshtml file